# Issue with Cropping Rotated Images - JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Problem:

When I rotate an image and then attempt to crop it, the cropping rectangle doesn't align properly with the rotated image, resulting in incorrect cropping. The offset seems to be related to the image's rotation, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Code:

```
  function cropAndResize() {
  if (isCropSelected == false) {
    return;
  }            
  let rect = cropRectangle.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = rect.left - photoContainer.offsetLeft + 2;
  let y = rect.top - photoContainer.offsetTop + 2;
  let width = rect.width - 4; //Odečtení tloušťky výběrového nástroje
  let height = rect.height - 4; //Odečtení tloušťky výběrového nástroje

  let currentFlip = getComputedStyle(photo).getPropertyValue('--flip');
  currentFlip = currentFlip ? parseFloat(currentFlip) : 1;

  if (currentFlip === -1) {
    x = photo.width - x - width;
  }

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = width / zoomLevel;
  canvas.height = height / zoomLevel;

  ctx.drawImage(photo, x / zoomLevel, y / zoomLevel, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  photo.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  cropRectangle.style.display = 'none';
  resetButton.style.display = 'block';
  isEffectApplied = false;
  isCropSelected = false;
  isCroped = true;
  updateButtons();
}
```

The complete code is here: [https://pastebin.com/](https://pastebin.com/MdUEGVnm)

What I've tried:

I've attempted to adjust the crop position based on the image's rotation, but my current approach doesn't seem to be working correctly. I've also checked various resources online, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my specific use case.

Expected Behavior:

When cropping a rotated image, the cropping rectangle should accurately align with the visible area of the rotated image, allowing me to crop the desired portion of the image correctly.

Request for Help:

I'm seeking assistance to properly handle the offset when cropping rotated images. Any guidance or code examples on how to adjust the cropping position to account for image rotation would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should try to use native transform functions here, they will simplify your code immensly. Instead of flipping the image, you could just use `ctx.scale( -1, 1 )` etc...